# Tensoflow model gives wrong output after conversion

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

My goal is to develop an app that does image classification. Keras model seems to work good but after i try to convert to Tensorflow Lite, output is completely wrong.

These are the layers of the model

```
model = Sequential([
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),
  layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(num_classes)
])
```

This is how i save and then convert the model.

```
model.save('/content/drive/My Drive/my_model.h5') 

TF_LITE_MODEL_NAME = "tf_lite_model.tflite"
tf_lite_converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = tf_lite_converter.convert()
tflite_model_name = TF_LITE_MODEL_NAME
open(tflite_model_name, "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Output is like this:

```
[[ 1.4364377  -0.02920453 -0.149581   -0.7537567 ]]
```

Why this problem occur?

Edit (Code that gives random input to the model)

```
# Load TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="/content/tf_lite_model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

# Test model on random input data.
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
input_data = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_shape), dtype=np.float32)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

interpreter.invoke()

# The function `get_tensor()` returns a copy of the tensor data.
# Use `tensor()` in order to get a pointer to the tensor.
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print(output_data)
```

Comment: How are the TFLite model's predictions wrong? What were the expected results from the Python model?

Comment: I used random data to test the model's output and the output is always the same with some very little differentiation(I edited the post with the code that produces random input). I also wonder if output can be neggative.